# Using same argument names in void function and main program

Tags: c++, variables, arguments

I've been wondering if can I use the same argument names in void function and main function.

Programs runs the same when I use different names of arguments in void function (int x, int y, etc.) and change the variable's names in the program itself, but I wonder whether I'm working on the original variables or just their copies.

For example if I assign integer b, a different value inside the fill() function, it won't change it's value globally. How come I can assign new values to the table and inside full() with loop and it'll be visible in both: fill() and main() function with new values assigned?

```
void fill(int a, int b, int n, int * tab) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        tab[i] = a+rand()%(b-a+1);
        std::cout << tab[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

    int tab[999];
    int n = 999;

    int a = 4;
    int b = 10;

    fill(a, b, n, tab);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my first post, I tried to search my problem throughout this forum, but none of them helped me.

Comment: Yes, you can use the same variable names in different blocks (i.e. {}). Also, it is not a forum

Comment: You might be interested in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this function:

```
void changeValue( int value ) {
    ++value;
}
```

Whenever you make a call to this function, it will take whatever value you passed as an argument, and assign it to `value`. Basically, the function call is creating a variable called `value` which initialization value will be the result of the evaluation of whatever you passed as an argument. This same `value` variable will be destroyed when it goes out of scope, namely, when the function hits it's closing bracket or the function returns control to the caller. Since what you are changing is a variable that was created when the function was called, it won't affect whatever you passed as an argument, since:

```
int x{5};
changeValue( x ); // The 'x' argument will evaluate to five when passing it as an argument
```

Remember that you can pass an expression as an argument to the function, such as '3' or ' 4 + 6'

It will evaluate to the corresponding value and then initialize the `value` parameter in changeValue with the result of that same evaluation. This is called: "Passing by value".

If you wanted to change the value of the variable itself that you are passing as an argument, then your function should look something like this:

```
void changeValue( int &value ) {
    ++value
}
```

Of course, you will need to pass a variable as an argument. This is called: "Passing by reference".

I recommend you to study more in depth functions, scope and references to get a grasp of this part of the language. Some useful links:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/
2. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Answer (score 1):

When you write a method or function in c++ like you did:

```
     void foo(int bar)
```

you do a "call by value". This mean that you copy the value of the parameter given to the function and assign it to a new variable. 
If you really want to access the original variable you need to do a "call by reference":

```
     void foo(int& bar)
```

The other thing is the name: the scope of a variable is normally within the `{}` brackets, so the scope of a local variable (declared wihtin a function) is always just the function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values by reference with &

```
void fill(int &a, int &b, int &n, int * tab)
```

This will pass by reference instead of copy, and will edit the original variables in main. Pointers get passed by reference automatically, so tab should be fine

Comment: Pointers are not passed by reference automatically.  Modifying `tab` in the function would not change `tab` in the caller.  However, you can modify the thing pointed to whether the pointer itself is passed by reference or not.

Comment: Sorry -- that is what I meant. Passing pointers by reference or by copy will still edit the contents of the original memory address.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the values by reference or use pointers ; but the first solution is easier